# An error in inserting pseudo code in LaTeX

Tags: algorithms, algorithmic, pseudocode, algpseudocode

I want to insert a simple pseudo code as follows, but I confront with an error and I am not able to resolve it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\State $i \gets 1$
\While {$i > 10$}
\State Statement
\EndWhile
\end{algorithmicx}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that I am using WinEdt 10.3 to compile my codes.

=======================================================

UPDATE:

I have modified my initial code based on the comment of a user and try to compile the following .tex file, but I still have a problem.

TeX file: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AsOHKyT9kjJO2T5_jgHT_niDnnmB

Error log: https://1drv.ms/t/s!AsOHKyT9kjJO2T0cTrj7E1Qe4gFX

It is worth mentioning that its MWE is also as like as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{My algorithm}\label{a1}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\State $i \gets 1$
\While {$i > 10$}
\State Statement
\EndWhile
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove `algorithmic` package and the other corresponding preamble, you would be good to go.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}

\begin{document}

        \begin{algorithmic}[1]
            \State $i \gets 1$
            \While {$i > 10$}
            \State Statement
            \EndWhile
        \end{algorithmic}

\end{document}
```

this would give you:

[image]

If you want to add `labels` and `captions` to this, just add insert the above-mentioned snippet within `algorithmic` environment into `algorithm` environment,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{My algorithm}\label{a1}
        \begin{algorithmic}[1]
            \State $i \gets 1$
            \While {$i > 10$}
            \State Statement
            \EndWhile
        \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

this would give you:

[image]

Comment: Copying and pasting the first code you have provided, I could properly compile the algorithm and get the output of it. But when it comes to the second code (with the caption), I face the following errors: https://ibb.co/g609pyw. Please help me to resolve this problem too. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: @Moosavi_69 Your log reads that for some reason, your caption sits outside the floating environment. May be if you post the problematic MWE, I can look into that for you ;)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I do not exactly know what do you mean by MWE. But I have provided the .tex file that I compile and the log of errors that I encounter. [TeX file] (https://ufile.io/wulab) and [error log] (https://ufile.io/16471). I look forward to your kind helps.

Comment: Please don't provide external unsecure links, could you update the `.tex` file in your question? For MWE have a look here: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that

Comment: I have tried to attach the .tex file into my question ( there is not a way to do so). So, I uploaded on a secure link (onedrive.com) for you and included them in my main question. If possible, please help me. By the way, thanks for the MWE introduction link.

Comment: I have also provided the MWE for you. Even trying to compile this simple code, the error appears!

Comment: @Moosavi_69 Finish it with `\end{algorithm}` (before `\end{document}`)  in your updated example. Then it should work. Because, when you don't end an environment, the floats will fly outside causing the errors that you posted in log (as a figure). Hence, let me know after you try, I should work ;)

Comment: Even adding \end{algorithm} does not make any difference. Still, there is the same problem "\caption outside float"!

Comment: In that case, you can post a new question and ask the issue. With respect to MWE, two things might go wrong: 1. delete your `.aux` file; 2. outdated packages?

Comment: I eliminated the .aux file, and instead of downloading packages from the internet, I allowed WinEdt to install the required packages. It now works. Many thanks.

Comment: Good luck @Moosavi_69 and welcome to TeX.se, also update your TeX version, your version outdated imo ;)